# How to translate this logical address into physical address?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Given that:

```
Logical addresss space=16
bits Physical address space=16 
bits Page size=2K
```

How the logical address 1027 will be mapped to physical address for the following page table?

```
p      f
0      9
1      7
2      3
```

Thank You!

Comment: p is the index in the page table and f is the corresponding frame in the physical address space. 
I have calculated the sizes of p which is 5 bits out of 16 bits and offset (d) which is 11 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

address `1027` maps to `p 0` because `1027 % 2048(2K)=1027  floor(1027/2048)=0`. So 1027 maps to `1027th byte of page 0` in virtual address.

Page 0 Virtual Address is mapped to frame number 9 according to page table.

frame 9 has a base address of `9 * 2048 = 18432` . Frame 9 has a base address of 18342 in the physical memory.

Now `1027th byte of frame 9 is at 18342 + 1027 = 19369` address of the physical memory.

change the numbers to binary and you have your answer.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655087/convert-logical-virtual-address-to-physical-address/11662516#11662516) and follow the link given there to understand the concept.

Cheers ...

Comment: O thank you so much @Deepthought. I'm new to memory management and was very much confused whether I'm translating logical addresses to physical ones or not. You have solidified my concept. Thanks. Going to choose  your answer as best! Thanks once again!