# Converting virtual address to physical address. Task solving

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

I have this:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0nob.png)

We have 64KB virtual addresses space, 32KB physical adress space, page and frame sizes are 4KB.

And I want to convert the logical addresses 20, 4010, 8300 to a physical addresses.

How can I find the physical addresses?

I tried looking at this : [Convert logical (virtual) address to physical address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655087/convert-logical-virtual-address-to-physical-address) but it wasn't very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You have to break the logical address into the page and offset. Then you have to use your table to translate the page to a physical page. Then add back the offset to the address of the physical page.

Answer (score 1):

page size = offset, when you translate virtual address to physical address, the offset will not change, you need the #page to find the #frame num from the page table.the add offset.first transfer 20 to binary, 12 bits for offset 4 bits for page num, 3 bits for frame num.